# Does Python Django support custom SQL and denormalized databases with no Foreign Key relationships?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've just started learning Python Django and have a lot of experience building high traffic websites using PHP and MySQL. What worries me so far is Python's overly optimistic approach that you will never need to write custom SQL and that it automatically creates all these Foreign Key relationships in your database. The one thing I've learned in the last few years of building Chess.com is that its impossible to NOT write custom SQL when you're dealing with something like MySQL that frequently needs to be told what indexes it should use (or avoid), and that Foreign Keys are a death sentence. Percona's strongest recommendation was for us to remove all FKs for optimal performance.

Is there a way in Django to do this in the models file? create relationships without creating actual DB FKs? Or is there a way to start at the database level, design/create my database, and then have Django reverse engineer the models file?

Comment: I'd love to see the rationale behind "Foreign Keys are a death sentence".

Comment: @Mike - The rationale is performance.  The rows being referenced in other tables are shared locked to prevent inconsistency.

InnoDB also provides no 'optimization' of how it locks these rows, and does them one at a time.

Comment: @Morgan: Rather than using foreign keys, I assume you just use an integer field with the related record's id.  Do you then handle all the row locking yourself?  Or do you just abandon normalization and combine the tables outright?

Comment: @Mike - I just remove the (forced) foreign key relationship, but otherwise the schema remains identical.  It's possible to write audit scripts to LEFT JOIN child on parent WHERE parent.id IS NULL to find any nasty rows that shouldn't be there.  I run them occasionally if it matters.  I do loose the foreign key cascade feature - which I push down to the application to manage.

Comment: Why not just put a NOT NULL constraint on parent.id?  And I think the a good follow-up SO question would be "Is there a custom field in Django that acts like a ForeignKey but doesn't use the FOREIGN KEY constraint?  What about OneToOneField?"

Comment: The NOT NULL I mentioned above is not because the column is set to NULL.  It's a trick to do a join, but only find the rows where one side is missing.

I had thought Django also depended on DELETE CASCADE, but a quick Google says it can emulate it.

Comment: I wrote about this here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/09/20/instrumentation-and-the-cost-of-foreign-keys/

Comment: maybe MySQL is the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want foreign keys, then avoid using

- `models.ForeignKey()`,
- `models.ManyToManyField()`, and
- `models.OneToOneField()`.

Django will automatically create an auto-increment int field named `id` that you can use to refer to individual records, or you can override that by marking a field as `primary_key=True`.

There is also documentation on [running raw SQL queries on the database](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

Answer (score 1):

Raw SQL is as easy as this :

```
for obj in MyModel.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_mymodel'):
    print obj
```

Denormalizing a database is up to you at model definition time.

You can use non-relational databases (MongoDB, ...)  too with [Django NonRel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel)

Answer (score 0):

django-admin inspectdb allows you to reverse engineer a models file from existing tables. That is only a very partial response to your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the model.py and avoid having SQL Alchemy automatically create the tables leaving it up to you to define the actual tables as you please.  So although there are foreign key relationships in the model.py this does not mean that they must exist in the actual tables.  This is a very good thing considering how ludicrously foreign key constraints are implemented in MySQL - MyISAM just ignores them and InnoDB creates a non-optional index on every single one regardless of whether it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the 'no foreign keys' advice (with the disclaimer: I also work for Percona).

The reason why it is is recommended is for concurrency / reducing locking internally.

It can be a difficult "optimization" to sell, but if you consider that the database has transactions (and is more or less ACID compliant) then it should only be application-logic errors that cause foreign-key violations.  Not to say they don't exist, but if you enable foreign keys in development hopefully you should find at least a few bugs.

In terms of whether or not you need to write custom SQL:

The explanation I usually give is that "optimization rarely decreases complexity".   I think it is okay to stick with an ORM by default, but if in a profiler it looks like one particular piece of functionality is taking a lot more time than you suspect it would when written by hand, then you need to be prepared to fix it (assuming the code is called often enough).

The real secret here is that you need good instrumentation / profiling in order to be frugal with your complexity adding optimization(s).

Comment: "if in a profiler it looks like one particular piece of functionality is taking a lot more time than you suspect it would when written by hand, then you need to be prepared to fix it (assuming the code is called often enough)."... Is this basically the 10/90 rule (work on the 10 percent that runs 90 percent), just applied to databases?  Because I can easily agree with that.  It just seems like going to another extreme to ban FKs, and like you said, it would "rarely decrease complexity".  Is refactoring the database after measuring performance more effort than banning FKs from the outset?

Comment: @Mike - yes, although I prefer to describe it as Amdahl's law <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law> :)  You can improve performance on a webserver by having more of them.  With DBs it's harder (the parallelism aspect is important).

I think we are in agreement, we're just using different terminology.  In many ways I still "use foreign keys", I just don't use the InnoDB feature to constrain them.  There's really no refactoring, and I'm not doing anything extreme.  I'm not killing kittens.

Comment: I should hope not, I like kittens.  And cats.  So, basically, you're saying to avoid foreign key *constraints*.  BTW, to make a link in a comment, put the link text in brackets, followed immediately by the URL in parentheses: `[text](URL)`.